# How many mls of vodka should i add to 400ml of beer so that the resulting mixture contains 12% alcohol?

Tags: percentages

Assuming that beer contains 5% alcohol while vodka contains 40%

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783139/new-mix-of-drink-with-different-strong-alcohol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New mix of drink with different strong alcohol](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783139/new-mix-of-drink-with-different-strong-alcohol) In the meantime, please [show what you have tried](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to get an answer.

Comment: So it would be a equation like x*0,4 + 400*0,05 =  0,12?

Comment: If that is the case is the answer 49.7ml correct?

Comment: @TobyMak In the meanwhile I would suggest to take a *bomb shot*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the amount of vodka to add.

The amount of liquid in the mixture is $400+x$.

As the liquid is $12\%$ alcohol, so he amount of alcohol in the liquid is $0.12 (400 + x)$.

The beer is $5%$ alcohol so the amount of alcohol from the beer is $0.05\times 400$.

And the vodka is $40\%$ alcohol so the amount of alcohol from the vodka is $0.4\times x$.

So the total amount of alcohol in the liquid is $0.05 \times 400 + 0.4 x$.

And the total amount of alcohol in the liquid is $0.12(400+x)$.

So.......

Comment: Oh i almost got it right.Got it wrong about the amount of alcohol.Thanks fleablood.

Comment: That's not quite exact as there will occur a volume contraction if  water and alcohol are mixed.  For example, mixing 50 ml ethanol and 50 ml water will give a total volume of 96 ml.

Comment: Pfft.... real worlds only important to those who choose to live in it.